# Does my account run the risk of being banned because of someone else's excessive votes?

Tags: support

Today, I went to my SO profile to check my useful flags, my progress for my next badge, etc.

But, I noticed a strange event (It is clear that the same user was voting my posts many times):

[image]

I had many votes, so many that the system automatically corrected and removed, then, I contacted a friend who is also a user of the site, I notified him of the event and he told me the following:

> You're lucky that SO did not ban you.

But then, does this mean that my account runs the risk of being banned for this?

And if so, what should I pay for what another user is doing?

Comment: I don't know about the ban but a script runs once a day or so that automatically undoes targeted votes done in mass by a single user. The reputation will most likely be back to normal within a day.

Comment: You're not going to get banned, *they* might be.

Comment: if you're not doing it yourself, generally you will not get banned.

Comment: Please review the comments [on this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50180415/17034).  Don't do it.

Comment: @HansPassant That page doesn't exist (deleted question?).

Comment: @pnuts Because you say that I am the owner of this question, when clearly I did not ask it, I only answered it

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If the system removed the votes then it's clear that SO/SE considers the votes invalid. You will therefore not be banned from the site due to those votes alone. If however, **you** were responsible for those votes, using a "sock puppet" account, then you might face a temporary ban. This is however unlikely to happen, given that you apparently have not received a ban yet, and have not received a message from the SE team saying you have been caught due to voting fraud.

The Stack Exchange has a system in place to handle "serial voting", and voting fraud, to protect users from stuff like this. It is also possible that the user responsible for those votes had their account deleted (by moderators), in which case the votes would also be removed.

Answer (score 5):

It's not unusual that someone thinks "wow, this answer is really good, I'm going to look at this person's profile".  Then "wow, look at all these good answers they've written", and skims + upvotes many of their popular answers.

Obviously the person receiving the votes has done *nothing* wrong, so the SO vote-fraud-detection system isn't set up to automatically temp-ban people on the receiving end up serial voting, either up or down.

For the same reason, it won't *automatically* ban people that serially upvote.  Mods may look into it, but if they don't find anything suspicious (i.e. no connection between the accounts, and the answers getting upvoted were good answers (not all negative score to start with)), then the automated system did its job with no further intervention required.

---

If you ever do find yourself looking through someone's answers, only actually vote on a couple of them in one day, otherwise the serial-upvote system kicks in and your votes are wasted.  Don't go looking for answers to upvote, go looking for good content from a user that's an expert in whatever subject so you can read it, if you want to actually read more from them.